# Int fields becoming inaccesible, after first click-in, in Traits/UI GUI

Tags: enthought, traitsui

I have a Enthought Traits/UI GUI application with several *Int* traits.
I find that all of these allow me only one access, after program start.
That is, I click in one of them and am allowed to edit the value, but just once.
The next time I try to click on the Int, it's unresponsive and I can no longer edit the value.

Comment: Please create a minimal (e.g. 10-40 lines of code) stand-alone runnable example which exhibits the behavior that you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, by switching from the *wx* to the *qt4* backend.

Comment: It would still be helpful if you posted a minimal working example to demonstrate the problem.  It is probably also important to note on what OS you experienced the problem.